# Content type provide to menu link

Tags: 7, routes, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7 and different content types.

I've got 'News' content type and want this be like a blog. So, provide News content type to menu link.

Click Content Type and after menu settings, selected parent item main menu but not seen on frontpage.

How can i provide News content type to menu link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on the [Menu Position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) module. This allows you to map a specific content type to a menu item without generating "hard linked" menu entries.

Answer (score 1):

What about using views for this?  So you generate a new view with content type news, set to only show published, order by news date field (From your news content type) and this will do you a nice list, with paging etc available from the view config.

EDIT - I notice this is a little late now, but might help others who want the question answered.